# Calling function during runtime based on function name match

Tags: c++, c++11

Apologies in advance the possibly vague Title, best I could come up with.

I have the following C++ and text file:

cpp file:

```
class Test
{
        int var1;
        int var2;

    public:
        bool set_var1();
        bool set_var1();

        bool set(string var_name);

        void process_file();
}
```

text file:

```
var1 value1
var2 value2
```

Objective - In process_file(), read/parse the text file, and for each varX in file call the corresponding set_varX().

One option, in function set(), compare var_name to "var1" / "var2" / etc, and
call corresponding set_varX().  The issue I have with this approach, as more
lines are added to the text file, the code becomes...ugly, with the long "if-else"
code block in set().

Another option, create a static map
   "var1"  set_var1()
   "var2"  set_var2()

set() will iterate over the map, and upon a string compare match call the corresponding func_ptr.  This option requires maintaining a map structure.

Though I prefer the second option, less code changes as the test file increases, is there another option.  Just thinking out loud, in set(), can I take the string var_name,  and prepend set_, and call set_var_name(), basically somehow avoid the string compare, which is done in both the cases above.  My gut feeling, in C++, that is not possible to do during runtime

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: No, you cannot call a function by its name at runtime. You need a map of string to function.

Comment: But does the class Test really need int var1, var2? Perhaps you can just store your variables in a `std::map<String, int>` ?

Comment: Please don't name your functions the same as standard library classes (`set`), it's just confusing.

Comment: @bennofs You are absolutely right, in the implementation I am using the map containing the varX string and it's value.  Actually, will be a std::map<String, MyStruct>.   MyStruct will contain function pointer to the corresponding set_varX() and the value of the varX.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're asking about reflection, which is not a feature of C++, so this won't be possible. As you pointed out there are solutions to the problem, but all of them will involve a mapping of string names to functions, and you'll have to construct/maintain that mapping yourself. The language won't do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve option 2 by making var1, var2.. self registering types. New keywords cause no code changes, only new types. Therefor the map has to be some kind of global object, singleton etc.

A very simple example:

```
struct Setter
{
    virtual ~Setter() = default;
    virtual void Process(std::string content) const = 0;
};

class SetterMap
{
public:
    bool RegisterSetter(std::string keyword, std::unique_ptr<Setter> setter) {
        setters[keyword] = move(setter);
        return true;
    }

    const Setter& GetSetter(const std::string& keyword) const {
        return *(setters.at(keyword));
    }
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Setter>> setters;
};


inline SetterMap& GetSetterMap() {
    static SetterMap map;
    return map;
}
```

Define and register some setters:

```
struct Var1 : Setter {
    void Process(std::string content) const override {

    }
};
namespace {
    bool var1registered = GetSetterMap().RegisterSetter(
        "var1", std::make_unique<Var1>());
}

struct Var2 : Setter {
    void Process(std::string content) const override {

    }
};
namespace {
    bool var2registered = GetSetterMap().RegisterSetter(
        "var2", std::make_unique<Var2>());
}
```

Use the setter map:

```
int main()
{
    std::string line = "var1: blablab";
    GetSetterMap().GetSetter("var1").Process(line);
}
```

Comment: You could really improve this answer by going into more detail and adding an example.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you might consider embedding [Lua](http://www.lua.org/about.html) and changing the syntax of the text file to something like:

```
test.var1 = 1234
test.var2 = 42
```

Here, `test` would be a global Lua table that you instantiate from the C++ side and assign a metatable to using [`lua_setmetatable()`](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_setmetatable). The metatable would have a `__newindex` method as described [here](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.2.html). If you're familiar with Python, this is sort of like providing a `__setattr__` metamethod—i.e., it intercepts assignment of non-existent fields and executes some user-specified magic.

The 'trick' in your case is to create a metatable in Lua that re-routes access to the `var1`, `var2`, etc. fields of `test` to a [`lua_CFunction`](http://www.lua.org/pil/26.1.html) wrapper that sets the corresponding field on the underlying `Test` object. After that, you can simply 'run' the file using [`luaL_dofile()`](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/luaL_dofile).

A quick-n-dirty example (tested against Lua 5.1.5) that illustrates the gist of the idea is appended below. (It needs to be compiled with `-std=c++11` due to the use of a raw string literal.)

This approach is certainly overkill if your needs are *very* specific/targeted. However, if you want/need scripting in your app, anyway, embedding Lua is a great solution.

**NOTE**: It is not strictly *required* to use a separate table (e.g., `test` in the example). Lua stores global variables in a table named `_G`, so you could instead set a metatable for `_G`. However, doing so is a bit of a hack; it makes the example harder to follow, and would limit some of the other ways you can use Lua in your host application.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <lua.hpp>

static const char* regkey = "Test";

class Test
{
  public:
    Test();
    virtual ~Test();
    void set_var1(int value);
    void set_var2(int value);
    void process_file(std::string const& filepath);
  private:
    int var1, var2;
    lua_State* L_;
};

static int set_var(lua_State* L)
{
    // Get the table, key and value
    std::string key = lua_tostring(L, 1);
    int value = lua_tointeger(L, 2);

    // Get the Test instance pointer from the Lua registry
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L, (void*)regkey);
    lua_gettable(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
    Test* test = (Test*) lua_touserdata(L, -1);

    // Execute set_XXX() as appropriate
    if (test == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Pointer in registry is missing or NULL, aborting..."
                  << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (key == "var1") {
        test->set_var1(value);
    }
    else if (key == "var2") {
        test->set_var2(value);
    }
    else {
        std::string errmsg = "No such variable '" + key + "'";
        lua_pushstring(L, errmsg.c_str());
        lua_error(L);
    }

    return 0;
}

Test::Test()
{
    L_ = luaL_newstate();
    assert(L_);
    luaL_openlibs(L_);

    // Point the Lua global '_set_var' at our C set_var() function
    lua_pushcfunction(L_, &set_var);
    lua_setglobal(L_, "_set_var");

    // Store our `this' pointer in the Lua registry
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L_, (void*)regkey);
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L_, this);
    lua_settable(L_, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);

    // Set up the metatable to re-route "foo = X" to "_set_var('foo', X)"
    std::string script = R"SCRIPT(
      test = {}
      local mt = {}
      mt.__newindex = function(tbl, key, value)
          _set_var(key, value)
      end
      setmetatable(test, mt)
    )SCRIPT";

    int retval = luaL_dostring(L_, script.c_str());
    if (retval != 0) {
        std::cerr << "luaL_dostring() failed (\""
                  << lua_tostring(L_, -1)
                  << "\"), aborting..."
                  << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

Test::~Test()
{
    lua_close(L_);
}

void Test::set_var1(int value)
{
    std::cout << "Setting var1 to " << value << std::endl;
    var1 = value;
}

void Test::set_var2(int value)
{
    std::cout << "Setting var2 to " << value << std::endl;
    var2 = value;
}

void Test::process_file(std::string const& filepath)
{
    int retval = luaL_dofile(L_, filepath.c_str());
    if (retval != 0) {
        std::cerr << "luaL_dofile() failed (\""
                  << lua_tostring(L_, -1)
                  << "\"), aborting..."
                  << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Test().process_file("config.ini");
    return 0;
}
```